# Decompress Gzip JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, zlib, unzip, gunzip

I'm getting GZIP type compressed response from web-service. Can anyone please help me how to decompress or decode the response.

Any help regarding this will be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: Have you read http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the example given in the site. But I want response to be displayed in browser. I'm trying to compress json web service

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: http.get('/', function (req, res) {    
var acceptEncoding = req.headers['accept-encoding'];   
if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bdeflate\b/)) {   
res.setHeader('content-encoding', 'deflate');   
} else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bgzip\b/)) {   
res.setHeader('content-encoding', 'gzip');   
}   
console.log(res._headers);         
res.end('{"app_id": "A3000990"}');  //JSON data   
})   
}))

Comment: just use `request` or `superagent`

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want to use Express and the `express.compress` middleware. That will figure out if a browser supports gzip and/or deflate, so you don't have to.

A simple setup could look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.compress());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send({ app_id: 'A3000990' });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

If your data is a JSON-string, you have to set the correct content-type header yourself:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(data);
```

Comment: When I'm trying to hit the http://localhost:3000 in browser its displaying "Content Encoding Error"

Comment: Using Firefox, I presume? Try another browser, and also see [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/945251) which might help you fix that issue in Firefox. Or try running it on another port (3001 for example).

Comment: Yes in Firefox Content type error is displayed while running in chrome and IE the page cannot be displayed.

Comment: With the exact same code I posted? I tested it on Chrome, Safari, IE10 and FF and it works just fine.

Comment: In my client code I'm trying to parse JSON-string using connect.compress() middleware.

Comment: Could you edit your original answer and add the exact code you're using now?

Comment: I have posted my code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496042/error-loading-webpage-while-parsing-json-string