# Error loading webpage while parsing JSON-string

Tags: node.js, json, zlib, node.js-connect, gunzip

Please have a look at my code where I'm trying to compress data using connect.compress middleware. How can I parse the JSON string in browser to get the decompressed data? When I try to hit localhost:2080 I'm getting a page loading error.

Client code:

```
var options = {
host: '127.0.0.1',
port: 2080,
path: "/",
headers:{
'accept-encoding': 'gzip'
}
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
var data = '';
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
data += chunk;  
});
res.on('end', function (chunk) {
var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data2.app_id);
});
});
```

Server Code:

```
app = connect();
app.use(connect.compress(console.log("compressed data")))
app.use(connectDomain())
.use(connect.query())
.use(connectRoute(function (router) {

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
            var acceptEncoding = req.headers['accept-encoding'];
            
              if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bdeflate\b/)) {
                    res.setHeader('content-encoding', 'deflate');
              } else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bgzip\b/)) {
                    res.setHeader('content-encoding', 'gzip');
              }
            console.log(res._headers);  
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end('{"app_id": "A3000990"}');
            })
            }))
            
.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.end(err.message);
  });

http.createServer(app).listen(2080);
```

We can't control the browser. It either sends the Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate header or it doesn't. So can we get compress data using connect.compress()?

Comment: does it work in the browser? what's the server output?

Comment: No in Firefox its displaying Content encoding error. In chrome and IE the page cannot be loaded. But in console the results are coming as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here:

- you're setting `Content-Encoding` headers in the server, but also use `connect.compress` which will also set that header. That could create conflicts, so don't add those headers yourself and let `connect.compress` handle all the compression;
- you don't actually send the HTTP request in your client, add `req.end()` to it;
- there's no attempt to decompress the compressed data in your client; how to do that [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776856/893780);

Comment: We can't control the browser. It either sends the Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate header or it doesn't. So can we get compress data using connect.compress().

Comment: What do you mean? Always compress no matter what?

Comment: Yes always the response should be compressed because we can't control the browser from client side. Our job is to configure the server so it returns zipped content if the browser can handle it, saving bandwidth for everyone.

Comment: That's what `express.compress` does, it will return compressed data if the browser can handle it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, they are essentially the same.

Comment: But in my above code when I removed headers:{
'accept-encoding': 'gzip'
}, the data was not compressed. Y it is so?

Comment: Because that is the way for browsers/clients to tell the server that they support compression. If that header isn't sent, `connect.compress` *has* to assume that compression is not supported.